# Reinitialize Kalthura mwEmbed-player-static.js after AJAX content loads

Tags: javascript, html5-video

We're using the mwEmbed-player-static.js library to handle playing video on a site. This works fine for a static page where we can load the script and that's it. But if we load the video tag as part of the dynamic content via AJAX, nothing happens. We need a way to reinitialize the player or reload the script. Has anyone dealt with this before?

Answer (score 1):

The source for [`Player_DynamicEmbed`](http://www.kaltura.org/apis/html5lib/kplayer-examples/Player_DynamicEmbed.html) has the javascript to make this happen. You can just call the dynamic player loader after the content of the ajax request has been processed.